# Affdex CameraDetector does not process frames

Tags: .net, emgucv, affdex-sdk

I just installed the Affectiva SDK on my Surface tablet, and I am now trying to use the SDK in an application. The camera starts, the light is on, but I do not receive any onImageCapture, or any onImageResults. Does anyone have any ideas on what to do to see why this happens?

Note: I used EMGU 3 library and with that, I can open the camera and see frames. So the camera works.

Best regards.

Comment: I also implemented Affdex.ProcessStatusListener, to see if there are errors, but nothing is sent from the Detector.

Comment: Did you try running the sample app [AffdexMe](https://download.affectiva.com/windows/AffdexMe-1125-win32.exe).

Comment: hello,

I just tried running the demos from AffdexMe. I get 'Failed to retrieve camera frames', error.

Comment: hello,

Apparently the issue is somewhat related to the default cameras of the Surface. I tried with an external one connected via USB, and it works. I cannot say what causes incompatibility with the Rear-Front cameras of the surface.